# Grab the first to fourth characters from string and change it to other character in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I currently have a `Gridview` with certain numbers of columns. In one of the columns, I have users' contact number, thus I want to **mask the first four number**. Is there a way to do it?

For example:

```
123456
```

I want to only have the last two numbers visible. Thus, the output would be

```
XXXX56
```

Is there a way?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAttendance" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped gvv">
    <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="userCN" HeaderText="Contact Number" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Grab the number in string format. A string is simply an array of characters so you can take the indices of the numbers you want to change and change them. I would probably recommend a for loop.

Comment: @Hank So there's no way I can do in the `Boundfield` ? I'd have to generate the `gridview` at the `code behind`?

Comment: The post didn't specify that you wanted to to it with XAML. My answer would require code-behind, yes. Are you just looking to mask it but still be able to access the full number in your program?

Comment: @Hank My bad. Don't have to, it's just for display purposes.

Comment: You can look into using a [MaskedTextBox](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/MaskedTextBox/Implementation/MaskedTextBox.cs) but I'm not sure if this will be a solution to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is creating a function that returns the anonymized string inside the GridView ItemTemplate.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# anonymizeString(Eval("userCN").ToString()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the function

```
public string anonymizeString(string input)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.Length > 5)
    {
        return "XXXX" + input.Substring(4, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Or as one-liner in the GridView

```
 <%#  (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("userCN").ToString()) && Eval("userCN").ToString().Length > 5) ? "XXXX" + Eval("userCN").ToString().Substring(4, 2) : Eval("userCN").ToString() %>
```